# Mercurial Eclipse- Error with initialization

Tags: java, eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I am trying to contribute to a Java project on Eclipse Mercurial. Whenever I do anything with Mercurial (like importing or cloning a Mercurial project) I get this error in a popup.

```
Multiple Mercurial errors have occurred. 
Please check the Error Log view for detailed information.
. Command line: hg -y debuginstall
. Command line: hg -y debuginstall
. Command line: hg -y debuginstall
```

I am running Windows 8 on a Microsoft Surface Pro 3, using Eclipse Standard. Does anybody know what I can do to remedy this?

I'm afraid the log is not much help either.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, apparently the Mercurical plugin with Eclipse did not come withe needed hg.exe

I downloaded TortoiseHg and pointed EclipseMercurial to the hg.exe in the TortoiseHg directory.